# ProgressBar value is not increasing

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, windows

I was adding a progress bar in my `login` form.

After clicking on `sign in`  button in `login` form, the`next` form gets some values from database(in form load), and then the `next` form opens after getting the data.

Now, before the `next` form opens, I want to display the progress of data fetch in that progress bar in `login`  form. So I have added the following code in `next` form.

```
Login login = new Login();

//loop...................

_recordCount = _recordCount + 1;

// Increment ProgressBar 

ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) login.Controls["progressBarMainPageLoad"];
if (_recordCount*10 < 100)
{
    progressBar.Value = _recordCount*10;
}
```

But there is no change in progress bar in `login` form. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you try to reference the current instance of the  Login form with

```
Login login = new Login();
```

when you are inside of the `'next'` form. But this line creates a new instance of the Login form and the progressbar control obtained is from this new instance. So you are essentially incrementing the progressbar on a form that is not displayed on your monitor.

To prove this adds a

```
login.Show()
```

before calling the increment.

To solve, well, you need to pass the correct instance of the login form inside this `next` form and reference it

Answer (score 4):

You should use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for your task.

Use `ProgressChanged` event to change your progressbar value and `DoWork` to get values from database.

Don't forget to set `WorkerReportsProgress` property to true.